# Subdomains for oauth process?

Tags: oauth-2.0, foursquare

My app allows users to have custom subdomains, as in user1.domain.com.  I am integrating various oauth providers, all of which support the ability to authenticate via oauth with a subdomain of the registered application domain.  Is there a way this can be done with Foursquare, or if not is there a specific reason subdomains are not allowed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to specify whatever callback URL you'd like via https://foursquare.com/oauth

Comment: I understand that a single callback URL can be set there, however what I am trying to do is accept multiple callbacks on the same domain (but different subdomains).  
So currently I have my callback URL set to _mydomain.com/auth/foursquare/callback_.  This works fine for requests originating from _mydomain.com_  However users have custom subdomains in our app, so what I am trying to do is allow users to authenticate from _user1.mydomain.com/auth/foursquare/callback_ as well.

Comment: that's not possible. You'll need to specify any custom behavior/identifiers as URL parameters in the callback.

Comment: @akdotcom maybe this is something to bring up at foursquare; facebook and twitter both allow you to change subdomains in callbacks, ie. if your callback url is example.com, i can, with twitter or FB use my.example.com as my callback url

Comment: This is rather annoying; I don't want subdomains, but I'm developing using symphony which uses a slightly different URL structure for the dev environment and the prod one and it ends up with the same problem.  Easy with FB, Twitter and LinkedIn, but not possible with Foursquare.